# how to differentiate a Folder Type(Windows/FTP) in MFC(VC++)?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

how to differentiate a Folder Type(Windows/FTP) in MFC(VC++)?
In my case I have a MFC Treeview in which i am adding list of folders coming from server , that folders are Windows and CIFS .Now i want to differentiate internally what type of folder are they because i select some folder and say connect then it brings up login page where i need to login credentials details , but before that i need to differentiate what type of folder is that ?

Any treeview property like setting and geeting key or any other approach.
Thanks in Advance.

I get folder list from server in this format volume1/Folder1,volume2/Folder2||Folder3,Folder4   in this below method i am removing "||" and maintaining them in two differnt variables: strDataFolder contains - FTP Folders and 
strNASfolders conatins CIFS folder , then one more method i am using UpdateFolder. If it is FTP then directly Add but if it CIFS check for duplication if that folder is already there dont add it again to treeview.

Now iam not able to get it how to differentiate what type of folder are they ?

```
void CNDSClientDlg::UpdateSharedFolder(CString strNASfolders,HTREEITEM hChildItem)
{
    CString strDataFolder = "";
    CString strData = "";       

    int iPos = 0;
    int fPosition = 0;

    fPosition = strNASfolders.Find("||");           
    if(fPosition != -1)
    {
        strDataFolder = strNASfolders.Mid(0,fPosition);
        strNASfolders = strNASfolders.Right(strNASfolders.GetLength()-(fPosition+2));   

    }
    else
    {
       strDataFolder = strNASfolders;
    }

    if (strDataFolder != "" )
    {
         UpdateFolders(strDataFolder,hChildItem,false);

    }
    if (strNASfolders != "" )        //don't add if already exist
    {
        UpdateFolders(strNASfolders,hChildItem,true);
    }
```

}

```
void CNDSClientDlg::UpdateFolders(CString strFolderType,HTREEITEM hChildItem,bool bCheck)
{
        int iPos = 0 ;      
        CString strData = "";
        CString strCurrFolder ="";
        HTREEITEM HShareFolder = NULL;
        bool bFound = false ;
        while (iPos != -1)
        {
            iPos = strFolderType.Find(","); 



        if (iPos != -1)
        {               
             strData = strFolderType.Mid(0,iPos);//get the folder details
        }
        else
        {
            strData = strFolderType;//get the last folder details
        }

        strFolderType = strFolderType.Right(strFolderType.GetLength()-(iPos+1)); //get remaining data
        int fPos = strData.ReverseFind('/');
        if (fPos != -1)
        {
            strCurrFolder = strData.Mid(fPos+1,strData.GetLength());    // get required data                                

        }
        else
        {
            strCurrFolder = strData; //else assign all the data 
        }

         if(bCheck == true)
         {
            bFound = false ;
            HTREEITEM hTempItem = NULL;
            CString strItemText = "" ;
            hTempItem = m_pTreeview->GetChildItem(hChildItem);
            strItemText = m_pTreeview->GetItemText(hTempItem);
            while(hTempItem != NULL)
            {
                if(strItemText != strCurrFolder) 
                {
                    strItemText = m_pTreeview->GetItemText(hTempItem);
                    hTempItem = m_pTreeview->GetNextSiblingItem(hTempItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    bFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }


         }
        if(bCheck == false || bFound == false)
         {

                HShareFolder = m_pTreeview->InsertItem(strCurrFolder,hChildItem);                   
                m_pTreeview->SetItemImage(HShareFolder,2,2);
                TTipItemData* pToolTipData ; 
                pToolTipData  = new TTipItemData; 
                pToolTipData->strTool = strData ;                                                                
                m_pTreeview->SetItemData(HShareFolder,DWORD(pToolTipData));

            }

         m_pTreeview->Expand(hParentItem,TVE_EXPAND);
         m_pTreeview->EnsureVisible(hParentItem);



    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items in treeviews can have arbitrary data associated with them.  Check out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ettyybhw(VS.80).aspx

The InsertItem method shown here has an `LPARAM` parameter.  This is for your use, and you can set this to some value that is meaningful to your application.

(EDIT: Alternatively, use one of the least convoluted overloads to insert your item and use `CTreeCtrl::SetItemData` on the handle that is returned afterwards).

To find out what value is associated with your item, use `CTreeCtrl::GetItemData`.

Minor Example:

```
HTREEITEM hItem = m_ctrlTree.InsertItem("My Item", TVI_ROOT);
HTREEITEM hOther = m_ctrlTree.InsertItem("Child Item", hItem);
m_ctrlTree.SetItemData(hItem, static_cast<DWORD_PTR>(10)); // set LPARAM to 10

// note, you can also store pointers!  This assumes pObj is some kind of instance
// of a class.
m_ctrlTree.SetItemData(hOther, static_cast<DWORD_PTR>(pObj));


// at a later point:
int myVal = static_cast<int>(m_ctrlTree.GetItemData(hItem));
MyObject* pObj = static_cast<MyObject*>(m_ctrlTree.GetItemData(hOther));
```

Comment: `CTreeCtrl::SetItemData` after you inserted the item works the same way.

Comment: @djeidot +1.  It's actually easier this way than pissing around with the large struct.

Comment: Can you pls give me some example on lparam how to use it ?

Comment: @Moo- juice : I saw your minor example but didn't understood how to use in my scenario.