# how to create new Property for MFC(VC++) treeview Control?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How to create new Property for MFC(VC++) treeview Control?

Comment: What do you mean by property?

Comment: @casablanca : I want to create a key property for treeview.

Comment: I still don't understand. Do you mean a tree item? Can you add an example to your question?

Comment: @casablanca: Pls refer to thsi post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263376/how-to-differentiate-a-folder-typewindows-ftp-in-mfcvc

Comment: There is already an answer about `SetItemData` there. Are you having problems using that?

Comment: I cannot use that approach as i am Setting tooltip using SetItemData now for this requirement i cannott use that.Is there any other way like creating key property for treeview and accessing it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SetItemData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk6c77ff%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) is the standard way of associating additional data with a tree item. If you're already using it to store the tooltip, that's okay, you can create a structure which holds all the data you want:

```
struct Data {
  LPCTSTR tooltip;
  // add other data members here
};
```

Then set a structure pointer as the item data:

```
Data *data = new Data;
// initialize data members here
tree.SetItemData(hItem, static_cast<DWORD_PTR>(data));
```

And when you want to retrieve the data:

```
Data *data = static_cast<Data *>(tree.GetItemData(hItem));
```

Also remember to `delete` the allocated memory when you are removing the tree items.

Comment: Can you tell me how to GetItem ID of selected node in Treeview ?

Comment: @Swapnil Gupta: You may find the [CTreeCtrl Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w95665f%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) useful. The function you are looking for is `GetSelectedItem`.

Comment: It gives me handle, I am looking for ID.

Comment: @Swapnil Gupta: There is no such thing as ID in a tree control, all the nodes are referenced only by handles.

Comment: Is there any way to get the ID ?

Comment: @Swapnil Gupta: What do you mean by ID? There is no ordering a tree control, there could be parent nodes and children nodes, so there is no way to number them as 1,2,3,...